# Meteor Unable to Render Dynamic Templates

Tags: meteor, iron

I am using Meteor with the iron:router package. I am trying to just render a basic template into a layout template, but keep receiving the error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Couldn't find a template named "/" or "". Are you sure you defined it?
```

For my '/' route, I have the following:

```
// router.js

Router.configure({
  layout: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('welcome');
});
```

My templates looks like:

```
<!--main.html -->

<head>
  <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name='layout'>
  <div id='container'>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name='welcome'>
  <p>Welcome</p>
</template>
```

For my package, I initially tried just installing the iron:router plugin. It seemed to add iron:core, iron:dynamic-templates, and iron:layout. I have since added each library separately:

```
> meteor list
iron:core              0.3.4  Iron namespace and utilities.
iron:dynamic-template  0.4.1  Dynamically create and update templates and the...
iron:layout            0.4.1  Dynamic layouts which enable rendering dynamic ...
iron:router            0.9.4  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform        1.1.1  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in yo...
```

Comment: Like saimeunt wrote there is no need for you to use <body> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `router.js` to :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout' // layoutTemplate, not layout
});

Router.route('/',{
  // give the the route a name to help it find your welcome template
  // let the default action function render the layout + template for you
  name:"welcome"
});
```

You can get rid of the empty body too, and FYI you don't need to manually add `iron:router` dependencies : that's what a package system is for in the first place :)

Comment: When using the code above, I still can't seem to find the template. I'm able to render it with `{{> welcome}}` (not using the router). I fixed the layoutTemplate config, and also tried hard coding it in the route) like http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#layouts.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the packages, incase I wonked something up manually adding them all because I was paranoid they didn't show up with `> meteor list`. The router works fine when rendering a single template, just can't seem to do anything with yields.

Comment: I seem to have things working with this syntax, it doesn't seem documented so perhaps that's outdated: `Router.route('welcome', {
  path: '/'
});` Thank you saimeunt!

Comment: Well, this is the old syntax that will get deprecated in version 1.0.0, you should stick with the newer syntax and `meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre2` to keep up with the cutting edge Router : http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/